# Can I use Notepad++/PyCharm like javaNetbeans?

Tags: ide, notepad++, pycharm

I am writing code in Notepad++ on Python2.7 Now I am looking for any way like java Netbeans providing for auto keyword detection. to be available also in Notepad++. Can I also debug my code using notepad++ as, currently running it from command prompt terminal. Also I would like to know if I can see the output here also without going to command prompt.

***Is PyCharm  a opensource IDE to develope python code?***

***Any opensource IDE is there, to develope python program?***

Thanks,

Comment: just a suggestion: use Vim or any other vim-like editor, it's the most powerful editor out there and it's basically available on any platform.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a best opensource editor/debugger to code on `Python` platform?

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ is a polyglot source code editor and not a Polglot IDE. If you need an integrated development environment for Python Development, there are both commercial and free/open source options available for you.

You can refer the following SO question for the list of Python IDE's

[Is there a good, free Python IDE for Windows? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126753/is-there-a-good-free-python-ide-for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Eclipse, an extensive IDE, - by far, Eclipse eclipses both Notepad++ and anything else. The best extension would be [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)

Relevant:
[What is the best python editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872640/what-is-the-best-python-editor)

Comment: is pydev open source software?

Comment: the link contains too many downloadble links,what I need to choose got confused,can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad ++ is a text editor.

Netbeans is an IDE.

i'm sure you can do fancy things with Notepad++ but for serious python coding you can try Eclipse which has a robust python integration ( code debugging directly in the IDE , breakpoints , console .... )

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is a **text editor**.  What this amounts to is nothing more than fancy syntax highlighting and *some* code completion.  Text editors don't give you the full range of robust tools and options, as their target is something between a full-blown IDE but without the bloat.  These generally presume that you can debug your code using third party applications.

Netbeans is an **IDE**.  An IDE's only purpose is to enable rapid development of software, so it adds in extra features, such as good code completion, refactoring tools, debugging tools, and certain IDEs can even integrate with a version control system (VCS).

Ultimately, the answer is "no", you can't really use Notepad++ like you would Netbeans.  But if Notepad++ has the plugin support for it, it's certainly *possible*.  It'd just be less painful to download Netbeans and use that, instead.

<sup>Alternatively, you can look into other non-free Python editors.  [IntelliJ](http://jetbrains.com/idea) and [PyCharm](http://jetbrains.com/pycharm) are two of the very best out there.</sup>

Comment: Is this a Opensource `Pycharm` IDE?

Comment: PyCharm probably isn't - I wasn't able to find anything about it - but IntelliJ is.  The only catch is that to use Python, you'd probably have to pay for it.  Regardless, it's well worth the investment.